# React setState re renders with old state

Tags: reactjs

this is my parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '../textfield';


export const List = () => {

  const [list, setList] =useState<string[]>(["bananas", "apples"]);

  return (
    <div>
       <h1>
        Shopping List
      </h1>

      <TextField createList={(userInput: any) => setList([...list,userInput])} />

      <ul>
     {list?list.map((item: string, id: number) => (
            <li key={id}><input type="checkbox"/>{item}</li>
          )): "list is still empty, lets add something"}
      </ul>
     
    </div>
  )
}
```

it gets the new item of the list from the form of child component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


interface Props {
  createList: any;
}

export const TextField: React.FC<Props>=({createList})  =>{

const [userInput, setUserInput] =useState<string | null>();

  return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit= {() => createList(userInput)}>
       <input onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}  placeholder ="add something to the list.."/>
      <button type="submit">Add to list</button>
   </form>
   </div>
  )
}
```

when i add the item the component shows the new item in the list for less then a second until re render accurs and then it's back to the old state...

Comment: Yup, It's the problem with `form submit` which will reload/re-renders the component.

Comment: it's reload re-render don't interrupt react as I  know
but the type any can make a problem in the future due do  him not be specific as a method that get one parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the submit refresh so you need to prevent it by do e.preventDefault()

```
  const handleSubmit = (e:FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      createList(userInput)
  }
<form onSubmit= {(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
```

another thing is when you use TypeScript try to be more specific about the type you use like this:

```
interface Props {
  createList: (a:any)=>void;//instead of any
}
```

just for notice:
In TypeScript you need to be more specific with your type and not just thrown any
like this:

```
 interface Props {
  createList: any;
}
```

because now you can insert there everything you want and TypeScript here to prevent that and let you decide the specific type so the code will not run if you insert wrong type.
try to do this:

```
interface Props {
  createList: (a:any)=>void;
}
```

Comment: you welcome happy to help
@TomerRajuan I just put another thing for you just for you to notice and upgrade you code
If you need any help I can give you my discord or slack and you can contect me there

Comment: I saw it now, thank you. yeah im just starting now with typescript so good to know that...